# How can I unseize a transmission pan bolt?

Tags: ford, transmission, mustang, stuck-bolt

All bolts were tight as hell. One last bolt I put everything I had on it, vice grips etc...

[Vehicle: 1995 Ford Mustang, 6 cyl]

This thing will not budge. Please help a brother out.Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post your personal email. The Q&A format should suffice.

Comment: This is on the transmission pan? What's the year/make/model/engine of the transmission we're talking about?

Comment: 1995 mustang.6 cyl.

Comment: Have your already fully removed all the other bolts?

Comment: This will sound weird but it can work : have you tried to tighten said bolt then undo - repeat often but don't shear it, that will be the last resort and only if you can get space enough to re-tap it...

Comment: yep tried,no luck.exhaust is welded and limited space.the prior bolt installer.grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: If you have a socket that properly fits the bolt you can set the socket and an extension and tap it a bit with a hammer to help breakup any oxidation and/or loosen any bound threads. Always err on the side of being gentle though because too much force could also start damaging the threads. Also the reason that I ask if all bolts have been removed is that if they are, then all the leverage will be applied to the last bolt, which will make its individual thread tension pretty high. I realize these are kind of novice points, but what the heck! :)

Comment: @kyle_engineer sometimes putting a nut into the socket first will help achieve what you explain...

Comment: @SolarMike I’ve never tried that, but I’ve never had to fight as hard as Scott has explained... except with a decking carriage bolt... (it had been welded. Facepalm.)

Comment: no i have never tried that .the bolt was already in bad shape.thats why i tried proper tools first then vice grips .and i got a good bite on vice grips .just would not give.impact gun is after said nut.if bolt snaps .ill curse and start drilling.lol

Comment: that was actually the first bolt i tried .said screw it and moved on.i have never had trans bolts on this tight.crazy.

Comment: thanks guys and gals.im trying every single hint i get.drilling is not my solution ,but end game..lol

Answer (score 2):

Three options, in that order:

1. generously spray with penetrating oil. Let it soak overnight, spay again and give it a go.
2. Heat the case and/or cool the bolt. (Torch and ice-spray)
3. Use a really long handle, will probably only brake the bold
4. Last option: Drill it out, reapair thread.

Comment: thanks im thinkinking same .last resort drill..it just grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrgggr  people think they need to torque stuff like this.thanks everyonew.

Answer (score 1):

I can not comment as I am too new to the site: Have you tried ATF/Acetone 50/50 solution as a penetrating liquid?

Comment: no but im going to try everything but drilling.last resort.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention an impact tool.  You should really consider either pneumatic or electric before you do anything drastic.  Borrowing one is a lot easier than fixing threads...